# Python Opencv draw rectangle from smaller frame

Tags: python, opencv, conv-neural-network, face-recognition

I am currently working on a face detection algorithm using MTCNN.

With the below code, I am able to show the frame containing my face:

```
`def run_detection(fast_mtcnn):
    frames = []
    frames_processed = 0
    faces_detected = 0
    batch_size = 60
    start = time.time()

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        __, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frames.append(frame)

        faces = fast_mtcnn(frames)

        frames_processed += len(frames)
        faces_detected += len(faces)
        frames = []
        if len(faces) > 0:
            for face in faces:
                cv2.imshow('frame',face)
                
        print(
            f'Frames per second: {frames_processed / (time.time() - start):.3f},',
            f'faces detected: {faces_detected}\r',
            end=''
        )
        if cv2.waitKey(1) &0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

FYI, the `cv2.imshow('frame',face)` is just for me to put some value there as I would like to get its bouding box.

Which looks something like this(please forgive my silly looking face):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lCGk.png)

This I just to show that it is detecting the face and its taking out the frames relating to my face.

What my challenge is, is how to take the smaller frame `face` (containing my face) and get the edge coordinates of it to draw a bounding box for each person in the `frame`.

What I tried is the following:

```
cv2.rectangle(frame,
                          (face[0], face[1]),
                          (face[0]+face[2], face[1] + face[3]),
                          (0,155,255),
                          2)
```

Which i assume is completely wrong.

Comment: You did not specify the version of MTCNN used and the format the data is returned in. The answer will depend on this. Assuming `x, y, w, h = face`, where w is the width and h is the height of the detected face, then you can draw a rectangle of the face as follows: `cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)`

Comment: Thanks!! this is actually correct. If youd like to put it as an answer and il vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution will depend on how the points are returned by the face detection system which can vary depending on the library you use.
In *this* case the detected face contains the following information
`x, y, w, h = face` where `x` and `y` is a point, `w` is the width of the bounding box, and `h` is the height.

Hence you can draw a rectangle of the face as follows:

```
cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```